# Square-integrable equivalent of Dirac Delta function

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta, quantum-mechanics

In QM we use position eigenstates $|x\rangle$ represented by Dirac delta function $\langle x' | x \rangle= \delta (x-x')$. They are non-physical because this distribution is not square integrable. I was thus wondering if it was possible to define a distribution $\chi (x)$ such that
$$\int |\chi(x)|^2 = 1$$ and that $\chi (x) = 0 $ for $x\neq 0$.

I imagine that even if such a distribution exists, its utilisation is inconvenient, but still I was curious about this.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: No, there is no $\chi\in L^2(\Bbb{R^n})$ such that (for any representative) $\chi(x)=0$ for $x\neq 0$ and $\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}|\chi|^2\,dx=1$.

Comment: In general, you can't evaluate distributions at points meaningfully. And definitely not the delta distribution.

Comment: Related question on MO.SE: https://mathoverflow.net/q/235827/13917 Related question on Phys.SE: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/135569/2451